# Minimum number of strictly increasing subsequences

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, recursion, dynamic-programming

#### Problem Statement

> Adrian is a runner and every morning he goes for a run with his friends.
> Every morning, their coach gives them a list of checkpoints from left
> to right to cover. Each checkpoint has a special value. Now, the coach
> has a rule such that a runner will only go to checkpoints whose value
> is strictly higher than the previous checkpoints. Also, all runners
> are supposed to move strictly towards the right. You need to find out
> the minimum number of runners it would take to cover all the
> checkpoints.
>
> The input is taken in the form of an array which denotes the values of
> checkpoints from left to right.
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> `[12, 15, 18, 17, 20, 25, 27, 19, 20, 21]`
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> `2`
>
> Explanation of the Sample Case:
>
> First runner will cover [12, 15, 18, 19, 20, 21] and the second runner
> will cover [17, 25, 27].

### My code

My recursive algorithm gives the correct output but it is not efficient enough.

```
visited = [0] * len(A)
def ans(A, visited):
    n = len(A)
    if visited.count(0) == 0:
        return 0
    num = 0
    ind = visited.index(0)
    visited[ind] = 1
    min_num = A[ind]
    for i in range(ind, n):
        if A[i] > min_num and visited[i] == 0:
            visited[i] = 1
            min_num = A[i]
    return 1 + ans(A, visited)
```

## Question

What's the way this problem could be solved more efficiently? My code was giving TLE on some test cases. I couldn't figure out how to make it work.

My code was giving the correct output. It is just not efficient enough.

Comment: what does your code output?

Comment: @Jpsh my code gives the correct output.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev my bad. There was an issue with the explanation. I fixed it.

Comment: This code cannot be correct. The function takes two arguments, and you call it with three.

Comment: @trincot again my bad! I corrected it. Just copied it differently.

Comment: See [Dilworth's theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem). Also [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-number-of-increasing-subsequences)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your algorithm has a time complexity of *O(n²)*.

You can use the following *O(nlogn)* algorithm:

Create an empty list, which will get one value per needed runner (so far). For each runner you will store the maximum value that the corresponding runner will visit (so far), and the values (once they get in there) will be ordered in descending order (invariant).

Go through the input once. For each visited value *v*, perform a binary search in the above mentioned list in order to find the greatest value *w* that is less than it. If found, overwrite that *w* with *v* (i.e. the corresponding runner will visit it). If not found, then append *v* to that list: this means an additional runner is needed. Of course, that will be the case when processing the *first* input value.

At the end of this process, the length of the new list represents the answer (the minimum number of runners needed).

### Implementation

For the binary search I'll use [`bisect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html), but you can of course implement your own.

As `bisect` only works on lists that are in *ascending* order, I will visit the elements from *A* in reverse order, and update the runner's information to be the *minimum* value so far -- as we are working in the opposite direction:

```
def ans(A):
    runners = []
    for val in reversed(A):
        i = bisect.bisect_left(runners, val + 1)
        if i >= len(runners):
            runners.append(val)
        else:
            runners[i] = val
    return len(runners)
```

Note: `val + 1` is needed to deal correctly with equal values (I assume integers). In the case there is a duplicate value, this means the same runner cannot visit it, so we should look for a runner with at least a value of `val + 1` (again: we are working backwards here).

Comment: isn’t this problem same as “calculate total number of increasing subsequences”?

Comment: @nomanpouigt, yes, the *minimum* number of increasing subsequences to cover the input. I have updated the question's title accordingly. It was too vague any way. Thanks.